# What does "There is nobody else I'd rather lie in bed and look at my phone next to" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "there is nobody else I'd rather lie in bed and look at my phone next to" mean?

Comment: Welcome to the stack exchange family. This is a reasonable question, but it could be improved. For instance, you can add some context as to where you found this sentence, and also provide your own interpretation. For an example of a question that has these properties, take a look at: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147659/whats-difference-in-meaning-between-variation-and-alteration

Answer (score 6):

It's a sardonic expression of romantic affection.

"lie in bed next to" implies a physically intimate relationship, which results in the two persons lying in the same bed together.

"look at my phone" refers to smartphones, and how they have become so ubiquitous many will peruse the internet after, or instead of, lovemaking.

Comment: In *Fiddler on the Roof* the matriarch is asked whether she loves her husband in the song *Do You Love Me?*. She responds *Do I love you?
For twenty-five years I've washed your clothes
Cooked your meals, cleaned your house
Given you children, milked the cow
After twenty-five years, why talk about love right now?* She then checks her cell phone (not really)